# Import csv file but not show image in magento home page and not a store in database table

Tags: magento, import-from-csv

I am using magneto 1.7.0.2 and I have import a product CSV file that file is import is successfully but image is not a showing on home page, 
and that image URL is not a store in magneto database,
 and I am using Local machine not a ftp.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Upload the images under media/catelog/product folder and change the url of the image in the csv file to this folder.